# Splitting Row values into Columns-TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have searched [SQL Server : rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274794/sql-server-rows-into-columns) for splitting row values into columns and it did not help me

I have sample data

```
Col1
0183125031218
13020690831
79100146868
0183225031138
13010690834
79100145497
```

Expected Output:

```
Col1             Col2             Col3 
0183125031128    13020690831      79100146868
0183225031138    13010690834      79100145497
```

My Attempt:

I have tried with `Row_number` fucntion, but did not get required output. As i need a conditional splitting by `left(col,2) = 01` to first column and `left(col,2)=13` to second column. Based on first column , row number can be allocated. There is no fixed length on any row data

Apreciate any help or suggestions

Comment: and `col3` should have all the rest of the numbers?

Comment: @ZoharPeled    Col3 based on `left(col,2) = 79`

Comment: What defines the relationship between `0183125031128` and `13020690831`? Is it simply that they are the lowest numbers in their respective groups? If the value `0183125031217` were to be added, would that the related to `13020690831` instead?

Comment: @larnu There is no relationship between them, it is simply lowest number as identifier for the groups

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your approach if there is no relation between the columns for a certain record. You might want to consider putting the values related into a seperate table.

Comment: Where does 13010690834 come from?

Comment: @paparazzo it is a transaction and left(col,2) has unique meaning, Data comes into a staging table this way. I have edited sample input by adding 4 in the end

Comment: But that is not in the staging table.  Rules for the three columns is still not clear to me.

Comment: @paparazzo whats the need for downvote ?

Comment: Was not me.  You want me to vote it down to prove it.

Comment: @paparazzo You can upvote if you think question is useful for others and answered well by respondants. I have good replies from everyone and foudn workign solution. I cant upvote you as it is not leting me do it

Comment: @Hadrian Not worthy of an up vote.  The question  statement is not clear.

Comment: @paparazzo Not a problem. We're all here to learn and sharing our knowledge, thats ultimate goal.Appreciate your comments anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query

```
-- test data
CREATE TABLE TestData(Col1 varchar(20))

INSERT TestData(Col1)VALUES
('0183125031218'),
('13020690831'),
('79100146868'),
('0183225031138'),
('1301069083'),
('79100145497')

-- query
SELECT
  COALESCE(q1.N,q2.N,q3.N) RowNum,
  q1.Col1,
  q2.Col1 Col2,
  q3.Col1 Col3
FROM
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Col1) N,Col1
    FROM TestData
    WHERE Col1 LIKE '01%'
  ) q1
FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Col1) N,Col1
    FROM TestData
    WHERE Col1 LIKE '13%'
  ) q2
ON q2.N=q1.N
FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Col1) N,Col1
    FROM TestData
    WHERE Col1 LIKE '79%'
  ) q3
ON q3.N=COALESCE(q1.N,q2.N)
```

And a variant with `PIVOT`

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      LEFT(Col1,2) RowType,
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(Col1,2) ORDER BY Col1) N,
      Col1
    FROM TestData
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Col1) FOR RowType IN([01],[13],[79])) p
```

Comment: Thats Perfect thanks, Only amedment with pivot as it is returning lot of rows with null values , i will eliminate null values with cte . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about using a CTE to assign the row number and grouping?

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (Col1 varchar(50));
GO
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('0183125031218'),
       ('13020690831'),
       ('79100146868'),
       ('0183225031138'),
       ('1301069083'),
       ('79100145497');
GO

SELECT *
FROM #SAmple;

WITH Grp AS(
    SELECT Col1,
           LEFT(Col1,2) AS Grp,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Col1,2) ORDER BY Col1) AS RN
    FROM #Sample)
SELECT G1.Col1 AS Col1,
       G2.Col1 AS Col2,
       G3.Col1 AS Col3
FROM Grp G1
     JOIN Grp G2 ON G1.RN = G2.RN
                AND G2.Grp = '13'
     JOIN Grp G3 ON G1.RN = G3.RN
                AND G3.Grp = '79'
WHERE G1.Grp = '01';
GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

This makes a more concise/shorter query than using the `UNION`s in leran2002's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The idea behind is to split the table into three columns based on given condition, then join them back based on `row_number()` without any ordering, as you told there's no relation between particular records.

```
declare @table table(col1 varchar(100))
insert into @table values
('0183125031218'),
('13020690831'),
('79100146868'),
('0183225031138'),
('1301069083'),
('79100145497')

select [col1],[col2],[col3] from
--IMPORTANT: here should go the query, that will have the most records!!!
(select col1 [col1], ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) [rn1] from @table where LEFT(col1, 2) = '01') [c1]
left join
(select col1 [col2], ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) [rn2] from @table where LEFT(col1, 2) = '13') [c2]
on [rn1]=[rn2] left join
(select col1 [col3], ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) [rn3] from @table where not LEFT(col1, 2) in ('01','13')) [c3]
on [rn1]=[rn3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the same as Larnu (+1)
I just wanted to test it

```
declare @T TABLE (col varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('0183125031218'),
       ('13020690831'),
       ('79100146868'),
       ('0183225031138'),
       ('13010690834'),
       ('79100145497');
SELECT *
FROM @T;

WITH cte AS
( SELECT col, LEFT(col,2) AS grp, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(col,2) ORDER BY col) AS rn
    FROM @T  
    where LEFT(col,2) in ('01', '13', '79')
)
SELECT G1.col AS Col1,
       G2.col AS Col2,
       G3.col AS Col3
FROM cte G1
JOIN cte G2 ON G1.RN = G2.RN
           and G1.Grp = '01'
           AND G2.Grp = '13'
JOIN cte G3 ON G1.RN = G3.RN
           AND G3.Grp = '79'
order by G1.col, G2.col, G3.col;
```